# What is the most consice way to generate a list containing 'key1' thru 'keyN'?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.6 and would like to have the most consice way to generate 'key1' through 'keyN'? I have tried without success:

```
Python 2.6 (r26:66721, Oct  2 2008, 11:35:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> N=10
>>> x = range(1, N + 1)
>>> 'key' + str(x)
'key[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'
>>> map('key' + _, map(str, range(N + 1)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> map('key' + ?, map(str, range(N + 1)))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    map('key' + ?, map(str, range(N + 1)))
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> map('key' + *, map(str, range(N + 1)))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    map('key' + *, map(str, range(N + 1)))
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: I think the question does not deserve a downvote. It's a valid question and it includes a set of approaches that have been tried. Since they don't work the OP is asking for a solution. Why the downvote then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list as output you can simply do this:

```
>>> N = 10
>>> ['key' + str(i) for i in range (0, N)]
['key0', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6', 'key7', 'key8', 'key9']
```

If you wanted to use `map` supply a lambda, something like:

```
map(lambda x: 'key' + str(x), range(0, 10))
```

However, as you can see from the answers there are other (perhaps cleaner) ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
['key%s' % x for x in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll say a *list comprehension* is the most concise:

```
lst = ['key{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
```

And you don't need to specify a zero start index with `range`

Answer (score 1):

```
map((lambda y: 'key'+str(y)), range(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat faster than the options provided so far is:

```
map('key{}'.format, range(N))
```

If you need an actual `list`, you can wrap in the `list` constructor:

```
list(map('key{}'.format, range(N)))
# Or on Python 3.5+ for even more concise code
[*map('key{}'.format, range(N))]
```

In general, I'd recommend a list comprehension based approach, since `map` with user-defined functions (especially with `lambda`s, where the listcomp can avoid the function call entirely) is slower than the equivalent listcomp. But with a built-in function implemented in C, `map` can win on both speed and brevity; since you specifically requested the *most* concise solution, this beats everything but old-school `printf`-style formatting as suggested in [yeharav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143624/364696) (which beats `[*map('key{}'.format, range(N))]` by a single character, three if you don't insist on PEP8 spacing rules).